# Knockout.js conditional binding

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, conditional-statements

How do you have conditional binding based on other properties?

Example..

```
var ViewModel = {
   IsAdded = ko.observable(),
   AddedBy = ko.observable()   
}
```

When I display it.. I don't want to show AddedBy if IsAddedBy is null or false

Something like this..

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: if (IsAdded != null && IsAdded) { AddedBy }"/>
```

I know that isn't right, but something like that...

Comment: Do you want to hide the whole input box, or just not populate it?  If you want to hide it entirely, look at the [Visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding.  If you don't want to populate it, then Tim's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 7):

What I would do is this;

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.IsAdded = ko.observable('True');
    this.AddedBy = ko.observable('Test');
    this.AddedByText = ko.computed(function(){
        if ( this.AddedBy() != null && this.IsAdded() ) return this.AddedBy()
        return "";
    }, this);
}
```

Then your input would be

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: AddedByText" />
```

This way you are keeping the logic contained within your ViewModel and separate from the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but it might help someone else looking

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: IsAdded ? AddedBy : "" "/>
```

Basically if IsAdded is not null then set the `value` to AddedBy, else do nothing